# Find missing negative element from array java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find minimum missing negative element from array.

eg : i have this array.

```
int[] {2,1,-1,-2,-4,-6,-7}
Output : -3

int[] {10,9,8,7,-1,-3,-5,-6,-7}
Output : -2
```

in above sequence the -5 or -4 elements are missing but I want to get output close to 0.
any help?

Comment: what was your approach?

Comment: The minimum missing negativ number will always be `-2,147,483,648` or something close to it. Do you instead want the maximum missing negativ number!? What have you tried?

Comment: sort the array, start from zero, count backwards

Comment: could you add your limitations, please? cause a for loop could solve it, but I don't think that this is your question (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the array will always be sorted?

Comment: I am missing your code right here. I can't guess what you did to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite contradicting as what you are expecting is the maximum negative missing array element which is opposite to what the question's heading states.

Store all the elements in an HashSet and iterate from the maximum negative number (-1) till the minimum element found to check if any element is missing. If none of the numbers in above range is missing, then the answer is `min-1`.

Here's an approach for finding maximum negative missing array element:

```
    static int findMissing(int arr[], int size)
    {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int min = arr[0];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            set.add( arr[i] );
            min = Math.min( arr[i],min );
        }
        
        for (int x=-1; min<=x; x--)
            if ( !set.contains(x) )
                return x;
        return --min;
    }
Feel free to ask any doubt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities depending on what you want. The first one finds the largest negative number closest to zero.

```
int[] data = {2,1,-1,-7,1,2,1,2,3,4};
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
boolean found = false;
for(int i : data) {
    if (i >= min && i < 0) {
        min = i;
        found = true;
    }
}
System.out.println(found ? min : "No negative values");
```

Prints

```
-1
```

This one finds the smallest negative number (furtherest from zero)

```
min = 0;
for (int i : data) {
    if (i < min) {
        min = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(min < 0 ? min : "No negative values");
```

Prints

```
-7
```